# apt-get does not work with correct packages piped from file

Tags: bash, package, apt, linux-mint

I have a weird problem with automating package installation with apt-get. I have a list of packages in a file say packagefile.txt. I want to use this list to automate the process of installing these packages by `cat packagefile.txt | xargs sudo apt-get install -q -y`. However, apt-get tells me on every entry `x`: `E: Unable to locate package x`. Of course I thought of typos first, but I manually tried apt-install -q -y on arbitrary package names inside the file, and everything works fine. The weird thing is, `apt-cache search` won't work either (not a single output at all).

I am using GNU bash version 4.2.37 on LinuxMint13 both Mate and Cinammon (both tested, too).

Could anyone give me a hint what might going on there, pleae? I am having a headache from trying out why that stuff won't work. Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Have you tried with `while read line; do sudo apt-get install $line; done < packagefile.txt`??

Comment: try `... | xargs -L1 -i sudo apt-get install -q -y {}`

Comment: Hi, thank you both for your replay! I have tried both already (without success). BTW: I am using 64bit version of LinuxMint13.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem on a raspberry pi - packages install fine manually, but won't install from a file (with any of the techniques mentioned here). Did you ever find a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each package is on its own line:

```
apt-get install -q -y $(< packagefile.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I realized the list of packages was built with Windows line terminators (CR+LF) that processed in Linux ended up in wrong package names (appended with CR). I converted the list with dos2unix tool and that worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).